# How to find a URL that can download YouTube videos fast?

Tags: youtube, download

The URL of the video is described in the HTML source of YouTube.

For example, the following is a video of 360p(itag=18) from
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g25V7k3J8p0.`

https://rr3---sn-ogul7n7d.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1663411914&ei=alIlY_zbLLCSvcAPweKB8Ao&ip=240b:c010:460:7f43:28ad:44fc:a7fd:a53d&id=o-APN7UpoL8PXUirzX2I1xN_IUB8QU0gPDCORsI4NT_HMj&itag=18&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=_R&mm=31,26&mn=sn-ogul7n7d,sn-3pm7dnes&ms=au,onr&mv=m&mvi=3&pl=52&initcwndbps=616250&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&ns=7cE-kpoUrFkmuk9r8BM8XgcI&cnr=14&ratebypass=yes&dur=20.665&lmt=1662988960680381&mt=1663390140&fvip=1&fexp=24001373,24007246&c=MWEB&rbqsm=fr&txp=6219224&n=6nRCWhxcp2KdWwLa&sparams=expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,vprv,mime,ns,cnr,ratebypass,dur,lmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIhAKlVetHQXpoD-ubRS8-zg4_011y5goeKzV3fCjP_COeQAiB3nBBjrh938ds8VBtZYZL2bck5Q8mPhaxI5KlKj4f1pg==&lsparams=mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl,initcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIhANDTDwOm_E07zyKhb3qUzp8dGKY_hZr1-2vK_EwoedPcAiA3QHQXSg2FXn4bfcHBcMdlGG-gt3lLnX3zX80wUVQrmg==

But when I try to download this url it is slow. 70KB/s.

On the other hand, if I use a YouTube download site (such as https://en.savefrom.net), the following URL will be extracted.

https://rr1---sn-g530uxow2-ioqe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1663412082&ei=ElMlY7jaGu2W2LYP3c2oqAM&ip=216.131.72.113&id=o-AFJFK2pnbiZoSpWLuAu79M0maZb3Qu5xdfDF-_6Ss2Ai&itag=18&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&spc=yR2vp1IgjyLsy4bpI3T537Nm15qgPPU&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&ns=pQxTog8SEWaLin2xwX5b0JYI&cnr=14&ratebypass=yes&dur=20.665&lmt=1662988960680381&fexp=24001373,24007246&c=WEB&rbqsm=fr&txp=6219224&n=l4yqz7hi7FyuEg&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Ccnr%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIgAs27z4CdSe0ChuDn_Mp5eZXitU-p68VU99nRA1fGE7ECIQCCRuTAXMkcafvIW7HgrLLhNUeriEu4cuMkbxviDBTpdA%3D%3D&redirect_counter=1&rm=sn-p5qeel7s&req_id=d2af52c30e3ca3ee&cms_redirect=yes&cmsv=e&ipbypass=yes&mh=_R&mip=240b:c010:460:7f43:28ad:44fc:a7fd:a53d&mm=31&mn=sn-g530uxow2-ioqe&ms=au&mt=1663390375&mv=u&mvi=1&pl=52&lsparams=ipbypass,mh,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhAJNVc1DLA8nH-SGMAH4cvvlF8uessMGq4T9_cGjStzuRAiEAzxZVHI-lbgwk891NMHOv2GifcQmjhph6M2aoithxjvQ%3D

This URL downloads fast. 1MB/s or more. This URL is not found in YouTube's HTML source.

Where can I find this URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to [SaveFrom.net's FAQ](https://en.savefrom.net/13/faq.php) they explain:

> "Why we have applied restrictions on YouTube.com videos »
>
> YouTube.com changed the link format, which is why we can no longer provide direct links to files.
>
> Now we provide YouTube.com files using our own servers. Since the **load has increased** manifold, we had to place some restrictions. Without these restrictions our service simply would stop working.
>
> We apologize and thank you for your understanding!
>
> You can download files from YouTube.com without restrictions by installing [SaveFrom.net Helper](https://en.savefrom.net/13/user.php?vid=389).

They download the video from YouTube (possibly recompressing, since they don't use the same URL) and provide an URL to a temporary file on their server (showing the common GoogleVideo.com URL, [source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38423549/3648282)).

To *create* the URL you must use their service, there'll be a limited time for how long the URL is valid, it's not a permanent (true link) to the video at that particular resolution.

I like most of the online services for downloading videos, but I use [TubeMate](http://tubemate.net/); it's fast and can use multiple streams for even faster downloading, unfortunately it doesn't reveal the URL it used, though it provides **all** the available resolutions (unlike SaveFrom.net), so that suggestion doesn't improve this answer (unless all you want is the video, as fast as possible).

Using another service, with an easier to use interface, (just stuff "SS" into the URL) I get this URL for that resolution:

https://www.SSyoutube.com/watch?v=g25V7k3J8p0

> https://www.SSyoutube.com/watch?v=g25V7k3J8p0  https://rr6---sn-vgqs7nlk.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1663484391&ei=h20mY-HALpeQsfIP0L2nsAg&ip=207.204.228.33&id=o-AJr4aghxdQdNXlka5uRQMV59h8BKGELQW2AB94nzPXmg&itag=18&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&spc=yR2vpwh0Pz87rshLCVHHjJbkLJ-tRlo&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&ns=nAA-5dO07BcBwaGRtbvEZ4oI&cnr=14&ratebypass=yes&dur=20.665&lmt=1662988960680381&fexp=24001373,24007246&c=WEB&rbqsm=fr&txp=6219224&n=FXvIvLy0pWLT0A&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Ccnr%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIhAJhaqBut7gMm1w8zVvJO_jAT1djUNL3iju4GQgjpHCa7AiAqO_o_5xZ0nxehmQ3PvZxSQ4iVezfEeAY4W9ZH-3OePw%3D%3D&redirect_counter=1&cm2rm=sn-a5mrk7l&req_id=e6af53668e53a3ee&cms_redirect=yes&cmsv=e&mh=_R&mip= (my IP address and remainder of the URL truncated, so that URL will be invalid.)".

- If you want an easy to use URL then https://savetube.org/ and their "SS" URL is probably the simplest, and it does download quite quickly.
- If you want the URL YouTube provides you can scrape the webpage, but they don't expect you to download any faster than you can watch; so the download can be throttled, since they don't want the video downloaded.
- The Android App TubeMate uses multiple streams so it downloads fastest, but it doesn't provide the URL; though it does provide far more resolution (and audio only) choices than most online download services.